# Invalid Foreach when testing error messages on login form

Tags: php

I'm back again. I've made this php code for the form-process.php;

```
    <?php
//prevent access if they haven't submitted the form.
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
die(header("Location: form.php"));
}

session_start();

$_SESSION['formAttempt'] = true;

if (isset($_SESSION['error'])){
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
}

$required = array ("name", "email", "password1", "password2");

$_SESSION['error'] = array();

//Check required fields
foreach ($required as $requiredField) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$requiredField])  || $_POST[$requiredField] == "") {
        $_SESSION['error'] [] = $requiredField . "is required." ;
    }
}

//Validating Text in name
if (!preg_match('/^[/w.]+$/',$_POST['name'])) {
    $_SESSION['error'] [] = "Name must be letters and numbers only.";
}

//Validating Drop Down Selection
$validStates = array("Alabama","California", "Colorado", "Florida", "Illinois", "New York");
if (isset($_POST['state']) && $_POST['state'] != "") {
    if(!in_array($_POST['state'], $validStates)) {
        $_SESSION['error'] []="Please choose a valid state.";
    }
}

//Validating an Email
if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $_SESSION['error'] = "Invalid email address";
}

//Ensure that the Passwords Match
if ($_POST['password1'] != $_POST['password2']) {
    $_SESSION['error'] [] = "Passwords do not match.";
}

//Final Disposition
if (isset($_SESSION['error']) && count ($_SESSION['error']) > 0) {
    die(header("Location: form.php")); 
} else {
    unset($_SESSION['formAttempt']);
    die(header("Location:success.php"));
}
?>
```

Login Form Div Error php code;

```
<?php 
       if (isset($_SESSION['error']) && isset($_SESSION['formAttempt'])) {
           unset ($_SESSION['formAttempt']);
           print "Errors encountered <br />\n";
           foreach ($_SESSION['error'] as $error) {
           print $error . "<br />\n"; } 
   } 
 ?>
```

However, when testing this on the actual login form I get this error:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in E:\XAMPP\htdocs\form.php on line 20

I'm pretty new to PhP, so there's probably something I am missing, but I can't quite put my finger on it...sorry

Comment: looks fine to me, sure this is the code with the error? remove everything else and see if you get the same problem

Comment: @Dagon Hiya, what do you mean by remove everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['error'] = "Invalid email address";
```

This would make it a string rather than an array as previously initialized causing an error with foreach.  Try:

```
$_SESSION['error'][] = "Invalid email address";
```

also

```
$_SESSION['error'] [] = "Passwords do not match.";
```

There should not be a space between $_SESSION['error'] and [], not sure if this would cause an issue, there are multiple places where there is an extra space in your validation.